# derivative trace of matrix inverse square

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

Consider matrix M = $\sum_{j=1}^n p_jf(x_j)f^T(x_j)$, P,X - scalar vectors, $ f=\left(1,x_1,x_2,x_1x_2,x_1^2,\ x_2^2\right)^T, x1,x2 \in (-1, 1), p_j > 0$. I need find solution for $\frac{\partial tr(M^{-2})}{\partial p_j}$. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\d{\operatorname{diag}}\def\D{\operatorname{Diag}}\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}$Define
the $f$-vectors a bit more concisely along with some related matrices
$$\eqalign{
f(x) &= \m{1&x_1&x_2&x_1x_2&x_1^2&x_2^2}^T \\
f_j &= f(x_j) \\
F &= \m{f_1&f_2&\ldots &f_n} \\
p &= \m{p_1&p_2&\ldots &p_n}^T \\
M &= F\D(p)\,F^T \;=\; M^T \\
}$$
And let's use a colon to denote the inner/trace product
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Write the objective function using the above variables and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= M^{-1}:M^{-1} \\
d\phi &= 2M^{-1}:dM^{-1} \\
 &= -2M^{-1}:M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1} \\
 &= -2M^{-3}:dM \\
 &= -2M^{-3}:F\D(dp)\,F^T \\
 &= -2F^TM^{-3}F:\D(dp) \\
 &= -2\d(F^TM^{-3}F):dp \\
\p{\phi}{p} &= -2\d(F^TM^{-3}F) \\
}$$
So there's the gradient. To enforce the positivity constraint use a
*projected gradient* rather than a regular gradient descent method.